# In Shading how do I make lighting physics from Cycles work in Eevee?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I was following this YouTube video that teaches you how to make stylized trees using a simple shading build that can react to lighting efficiently. Unfortunately, this trick only works in Cycles, I was hoping to make a flexible build that can work on both engines just in case if I need to switch between them. The image on the top is in Cycles while the one on the bottom is in Eevee, I think it's pretty clear which one's better but, in any case, how do I achieve that same level of detail in Cycles? [image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GgX70Jge" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GgX70Jge/)

Comment: Eevee manage the light differently than Cycles, maybe that's what you've noticed, but there's no real way to avoid that, or please be more specific?

Comment: Well how do I match the color from Cycles to Eevee because it doesn't look bright or lush in Eevee.

Comment: That's how Eevee works and it has nothing to do with your material, you need to find tricks to correct that if you don't like the current result, like for example adding lights, etc